# Spatie media library getMedia() not returning all images

Tags: laravel

I am receiving multiple images in base64 from rich text editor. My idea was to upload all the images and replace base64 img src in article content with newly created image path. I am using spatie media library and Laravel.

```
foreach ($data['images'] as $image) {
    $article->addMediaFromBase64($image)->toMediaCollection('article-images');
    $mediaItems = $article->getMedia('article-images');
    $article->content = str_replace($image, $mediaItems[count($mediaItems) - 1]->getFullUrl(), $article->content);
    $article->save();
}
```

The problem I have is that $article->getMedia('article-images') always returns only the first created image and the count is always one. So what ends up happening is no matter how many images I upload it will replace all their src tags with the url of the first image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the final solution I went with. The relationship was probably cached after the first image upload and that's probably why I was always getting the first image. After loading media relation on the model, I was able to retrieve all images in the collection properly.

```
foreach ($data['images'] as $image) {
     $article->addMediaFromBase64($image)->toMediaCollection('article-images');
     $mediaItems = $article->load('media')->getMedia('article-images');
     $article->content = str_replace($image, $mediaItems[count($mediaItems) - 1]->getFullUrl(), $article->content);
}
```